Removing console.logs using "drop_console" in metro.config does not work
Using the drop_console option into metro.config.js as per documentation here does not remove console.logs from the production build.
const { getSentryExpoConfig } = require('@sentry/react-native/metro');


module.exports = (() => {
  const config = getSentryExpoConfig(__dirname);

  const { transformer, resolver } = config;

  config.transformer = {
    ...transformer,
    babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
  };

  config.transformer.minifierConfig = {
    compress: {
      drop_console: true,
    },
  };
  config.resolver = {
    ...resolver,
    assetExts: resolver.assetExts.filter((ext) => ext !== "svg"),
    sourceExts: [...resolver.sourceExts, "svg"],
  };

  return config;
})();

Here is the full configuration. Also tested without SentryExpoConfig, same result.
What am I missing?
Thanks!
Built the production application for both iOS and Android and checked the resulted files and logs. The console.logs are still there.

Does this answer your question? How can remove console.log in the production build of a React application created using create-react-app?

@luuk Nope, I want to find the solution of the above, not rewriting the console.log function (which I secretly did until I find the answer for this question).
